# Can't scroll heroku maintenance page on iphone

Tags: ios, css, heroku, iframe, overflow

I have a custom maintenance page on my Heroku app and I can't scroll it on my iphone (neither on safari or chrome). It works correctly on the web (safari, even responsive mode, and chrome) and on android phones.

The thing is that Heroku loads my page inside an `iframe` with the following code:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Offline for Maintenance</title>
    <style media="screen">
      html,body,iframe {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      html,body {
        height: 100%;
        overflow: hidden;
      }
      iframe {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        border: 0;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
      <iframe src="//s3.amazonaws.com/cf-udon-maintenance-page/index.html">
      // Here goes my page
      </iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is the part that is breaking the scrolling on iOS, if I unset this property on debug mode the scrolling starts working

```
html,body {
   overflow: hidden;
}
```

Since I'm inside of the `iframe` I can't access this to override it, and I haven't found a way to fix it from inside the `iframe`.

Any ideas?
I'm sure this wasn't happening before, is this a recent change on Heroku's side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can only edit what's inside I frame, try the code below.
In style add,

```
  html, body, .wrapper{
    height: 100%;
  }

  .footer{
    position: unset;
  }

  .wrapper{
    overflow: scroll;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  }
```

And add a wrapper right below body tag

```
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <!-- Fixed navbar -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    </nav>

    <div class="jumbotron">
      <h1>Dang It</h1>
    </div>

    <!-- Begin page content -->
    <div class="container">
    </div>

    <footer class="footer">
    </footer>
  </div>
<body>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/dknfmqaL/

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a wrapper around the iframe. The below code seems to be able to scroll. But the header does not fix at the top.
I guess iFrame height on iOS may be not working properly.

```
<style type="text/css">
    .scroll-wrapper {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
        overflow-y: scroll;
    }
    iframe{
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        border:0;
        border-bottom: 1px solid white; /* <- required in order for scrolling to work */
    }
</style>

<div class="scroll-wrapper">
    <iframe src="//s3.amazonaws.com/cf-udon-maintenance-page/index.html">
        // Here goes my page
    </iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't control anything outside the `iframe` therefore I can't add a wrapper around it. My code get's placed inside the `iframe` by Heroku